# trying to copy the values from one row to another using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Can some one help me with this please because im banging my head against a wall now :(

I have a table with roughly 13 columns connected to this is a Jquery context menu, where the user can right click on the table and select copy down if they do this then i need to copy the value from the selected row down to the other rows, so far i have a JQuery function which is working to an extent, but for some reason when i run this it adds a new row to the table is not what i want, all i want to do is copy the values from the row and populate the other rows without adding a new row is that possible?

heres my JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('#grdvHandSets>tbody>tr').contextMenu([
        {
        'Copy Down': function(menuItem, menu) {
            var tr = $(this),
                tr2 = $(this).clone(true, true).insertAfter(this)
                tr.find(':input:not(.phonenumber)').each(function() {
                    //console.log(this.id)
                    tr2.find("[id='" + this.id + "']").val($(this).val())
                })
                tr2.find('.phonenumber').val('')
                $('#grdvHandSets .gvItem').each(function(i) {
                    $(this).text(i + 1)
                })
        }}
    ], {
        theme: 'vista'
    })
})​
```

Can some one please help me.... :(

Comment: _"for some reason when i run this it adds a new row"_ - That would be because you use `.clone()` (which makes a copy). Could you please show a sample of your HTML? Also, when you say "copy down to the other rows" does that mean rows above the selected row do not receive the copied values?

Comment: Look at your question source now after my edit, please learn how indention is made here.

Comment: When someone has answered your question, click the check box next to the answer. This helps build your reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write this code yourself? Its making a new row because that's what you're telling it to do:

```
tr2 = $(this).clone(true, true).insertAfter(this)
```

To get all the rows after your current one, you can use the [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) function.

```
tr2 = tr.nextAll();
```

You will probably also want to rename `tr2` to something more logical, like `nextRows`

Comment: No im picking this up from someone that has currently left the company, iv never done Jquery so im learning it as i go along, and this is what was left when he left, basically what ever row they click on and select copy down i need to copy the values from that row on to the other not insert a new row hope that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks Andy Ray this worked changed the following line and now is working fine, one more question if you dont mind, i just been informed user will have the ability to choose how many columns there should be in the table so for example there will be a text box and a button above the table what ever number they enter in the textbox will determine how many rows there will be, when i add the number 20 in the text box and press the button it adds 20 rows which is fine but when i right click the table after adding the rows the context menu no longer works?

Comment: that probably has to do with the contextMenu plugin you're using, it probably assigns the right click event to the selector you pass in, but if you dynamically add new rows that happens after the click event has been assigned. Look at the contextMenu plugin docs and open a new question if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters by using:

```
tr2 = $(this).clone(true, true).insertAfter(this)
```

It will generate your new entry. You should change the text/html of the rows. Insert actually append new elements and in this case it is a reference of your selected line.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, what do you mean by change the text/HTML im new to JQuery so im learning as i go...